# Convergence of regularized optimization problems to constraint optimization problem

Tags: reference-request, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, regularization

I have seen many times the following fact, which seems to be folklore knowledge. Assume that you have an optimization problem of the form
$$\min_{x \in \mathcal{X}} F(x) + \lambda G(x)$$
with $F$ and $G$ some strictly convex non-negative functionals such that $\min F = 0$ (the min is reached) and $\lambda > 0$. There exists a unique minimiser to this problem, denoted by $x_\lambda^*$.
Then, $x_\lambda^*$ converges when $\lambda \rightarrow 0$ to the unique solution $x^*$ to
$$\min_{x \in \mathcal{X}, \ F(x) = 0} G(x).$$
Is this result true, and has it been proven for some general context (eg infinite dimensional space $\mathcal{X}$) for some reasonable condition on $F$ and $G$.

A typical example is for $\mathcal{X}= \mathbb{R}^n$, $F(x) = \| A x - y \|^2_2$ with $y \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{mn}$ and $G(x)= \| x\|^2_2$. This corresponds to the Tychonov inverse problem
$$\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \| y - A x \|^2_2 + \lambda \| x \|_2^2.$$

I am curious about a general theory for such problems.

**Edit:**
The response to my question is that this is not the case in general, in particular for non-closed domains $\mathcal{X}$ (see a simple example in the comment and a detailed one responding to this post). However, the result is true over compact domains under reasonable assumptions (again, see the answer).

Comment: The above does not make sense to me. Why would $F(x) = 0$ have anything to do with a $\min$? Is $\lambda \to \infty$?

Comment: Correct, I was assuming that $F$ reaches its minimum and that this minimum is $0$. Moreover, $\lambda \rightarrow 0$. I corrected. Thanks.

Comment: This is a standard penalty method. Usually it is written as $\min \rho F(x) + G(x)$ where $\rho=1/\lambda\to\infty$.

Comment: Thank you, very relevant indeed. Would you have some reference(s) to suggest?

Comment: You really need to clarify what are the costs and constraints.

Comment: Let $\mathcal{X}=[0,1)$. Let $F(x)=x^2$ and $G(x)=(x-2)^2$ and $\lambda=1$. The first problem has no minimizer.

Comment: Also if $F$ is strictly convex over its domain and achieves a min of $0$ at some $x^*$ in its domain, then $x^*$ is the only point in the domain that maps to zero so it is the only possible solution to the second problem. In other words the minimum of $G$ in the second problem is not important.

Comment: I also observe that if your matrix $A$ has nontrivial nullspace then your example function $||Ax-y||^2$ is not strictly convex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to my comments, here is a useful counter-example in which $x_{\lambda}^*$ is always defined, but $\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow 0^+}x_{\lambda}^* \neq x^*$.

Define the convex set $\mathcal{X}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ by
$$\mathcal{X}= \{(0,1/2)\} \cup (0,1]\times [1/2,1]$$
The set $\mathcal{X}$ is a rectangle with some of the border thrown away.

Define the strictly convex functions $F:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $G:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by:
\begin{align}
F(x,y) &=  x^2+\frac{x^2}{y} \quad \forall (x,y)\in \mathcal{X}\\
G(x,y) &=(y-1)^2+ (x-1)^2 \quad \forall (x,y)\in \mathcal{X}
\end{align}

Observe that $F$ is nonnegative and $F(0,1/2)=0$, so $(0,1/2)$ is the unique minimizer of $F$. That is, $(0,1/2)$ is the unique element of the domain $\mathcal{X}$ that function $F$ maps to $0$.

For $\lambda \in (0, 1]$, the unique minimizer of $F(x,y)+\lambda G(x,y)$ over all $(x,y) \in \mathcal{X}$ can be shown to be
$$(x_{\lambda}^*,y_{\lambda}^*)=\left( \frac{2\lambda}{4+2\lambda}, 1\right)$$
Then
$$ \boxed{\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow 0^+}(x_{\lambda}^*,y_{\lambda}^*) = (0, 1) \neq (0,1/2)}$$

---

Strict convexity of $G$ is easy to verify. To show $F$ is strictly convex, let $(x,y)$ and $(a,b)$ be distinct elements of $\mathcal{X}$ and let $p \in (0,1)$. We have two cases:

1. If $x=a$ then $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq b$ (since $(x,y)$ and $(a,b)$ are distinct, and there is only one point in $\mathcal{X}$ with $x$-coordinate $0$) and so

\begin{align}
F(p(x,y)+(1-p)(a,b))&=F(x,py+(1-p)b) \\
&= x^2+\frac{x^2}{py+(1-p)b} \\
&<x^2+x^2\left(p\frac{1}{y}+(1-p)\frac{1}{b}\right)\\
&=pF(x,y)+(1-p)F(x,b)\\
&=pF(x,y)+(1-p)F(a,b)
\end{align}

2. If $x\neq a$ then we can define the convex function $h:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $h(x,y)=x^2/y$ and
   \begin{align}
   F(p(x,y)+(1-p)(a,b))&=(px+(1-p)a)^2 + h(p(x,y)+(1-p)(a,b))\\
   &\leq (px+(1-p)a)^2 + ph(x,y) + (1-p)h(a,b)\\
   &< px^2+(1-p)a^2 + ph(x,y) + (1-p)h(a,b)\\
   &= pF(x,y)+(1-p)F(a,b)
   \end{align}
   $\Box$

---

On the positive side, fix $m$ as a positive integer and suppose:

- $\mathcal{X}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m$ is a compact set.
- $F:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is any continuous function that has a unique minimizer $x^*\in \mathcal{X}$.
- $G:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is any nonnegative and continuous function.

**Claim:** Let $x^*\in \mathcal{X}$ be the unique minimizer of $F$. Let $\{s_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be any sequence of nonnegative numbers that satisfy $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} s_n=0$. For each positive integer $n$ let $x_n^*\in \mathcal{X}$ be any minimizer of $F(x) + s_nG(x)$. Then
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_n^*=x^*$$

**Proof:** Fix $n$ as a positive integer. By definition of $x_n^*$ being a minimizer of $F+s_nG$ we have
$$ F(x_n^*)+s_nG(x_n^*)\leq  F(x^*)+s_nG(x^*)$$
Since $s_nG(x_n^*)\geq 0$ we have
$$ F(x_n^*)\leq F(x^*) + s_nG(x^*) $$
Since $F(x^*)\leq F(x_n^*)$ we have
$$ F(x^*)\leq F(x_n^*)\leq F(x^*) + s_nG(x^*) \quad \forall n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$$
Taking $n\rightarrow\infty$ yields
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} F(x_n^*)=F(x^*) \quad (Eq. *)$$
Suppose $x_n^*$ does not converge to $x^*$ (we reach a contradiction). Then there is some $\epsilon>0$ for which $||x^*-x_n^*||\geq \epsilon$ infinitely often.   So there is an infinite subsequence $\{x_{n[k]}^*\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ such that $x_{n[k]}^*$ is in the compact set $\mathcal{X}\cap \{x:||x^*-x||\geq \epsilon\}$ for all $k$. It follows by the Bolzano-Wierstrass theorem that there exists a further infinite subsequence $\{x_{n[k_i]}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ that converges to a point $y\in \mathcal{X}\cap \{x:||x^*-x||\geq \epsilon\}$. By continuity of $F$ and (Eq *) we obtain $F(y)=F(x^*)$. Thus, $y$ is **also** a minimizer of $F$. Since $y$ is at least a distance $\epsilon$ away from $x^*$, we have $y\neq x^*$, which contradicts uniqueness of the minimizer of $F$. $\Box$

*For the claim, the functions $F$ and $G$ are not required to be convex. However, the function $F$ satisfies the assumptions of the claim in the special case when $F$ is continuous and strictly convex, since any such function defined over a compact domain must have a unique minimizer.*

Comment: Thanks a lot, both for the counterexample and the argument for compact domain (indeed a very reasonable assumption). My guess is that this argument extend to unbounded closed domains for instance adding coercivity of the functions $F$ and $G$, would you agree?

Comment: Just seeing your comment now (have been away). Yes, I believe that, at least in $\mathbb{R}^n$, we can extend to unbounded closed domains $\mathcal{X}$ when we assume $F(x) + s_nG(x)$ has a well defined minimizer $x_n^* \in \mathcal{X}$ for each $n$ (such as when certain coercivity assumptions hold).

Comment: I think a proof when $\mathcal{X}$ is closed but unbounded can be formed by taking the $x_n^*$ sequence of the previous proof and defining $y_n^*=p_nx_n^*+(1-p_n)x^*$ where $p_n \in [0,1]$ is defined to ensure $||x^*-y_n^*||\leq 1$. Now, just like $x_n^*$, we also have $F(y_n^*)\rightarrow F(x^*)$, but $\{y_n^*\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is in the closed and bounded set $\mathcal{X}\cap \{x:||x-x^*||\leq 1\}$.